# Match values in a multidemsional array

Tags: php

I would like to search an array for one value in a key and return the content from another key in the same array. 
Like this:

```php
 $cars = array
  (
  array("brand" => "Volvo","color" => 22),
  array("brand" => "BMW","color" => 15),
  array("brand" => "Saab","color" => 5),
  array("brand" => "Land Rover","color" => 17)
  );

// Not working, just to clarify my intention
if($cars['brand'] == 'BMW') {echo $cars['color'];}
```

In this example, 15 should be echoed.
How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Wrap that under a loop and it will work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
foreach($cars as $car) {
    if($car['brand'] == 'BMW') {
        echo $car['color'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a loop that goes through each possible value. Often, you'd just use a for loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cars); $i++) {
    if($cars[$i]['brand'] == "BMW")
        echo $cars[$i]['color'];
}
```

However, using a foreach loop is also an option, and it looks neater.

```
foreach($cars as $v) {
    if($v['brand'] == "BMW")
        echo $v['color'];
}
```

See the array, for loop and foreach loop documentation for more information

- [Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [For loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)
- [Foreach loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_filter` function in PHP. See [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) from the PHP docs and the given example.